Large floating element next to automatically sized elements
In HTML, an element is in flow or out of flow.
float: right can be used to take elements out of flow.
In-flow and out-of-flow elements can be combined, i.e. some elements can be in flow while others float out of flow next to them.
A flexbox (particularly with flex: auto) can be used to automatically nicely adjust the size of in-flow elements.
But using a flexbox to slightly adjust in-flow elements completely breaks out-of-flow elements: The float: right element stops floating right, and stops spanning several rows:


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.container span {
  flex: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
.container .float {
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
<div class="container">flexbox
  <span class="float">multiline<br>float</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
  <span>element with much content</span>
</div>



How can a layout be achieved where some elements have automatically adjusted sizes (like they would with flex: auto) while other large elements float and span several rows? Ideally, it shouldn't be too hacky (such as painting on a <canvas>).

Please edit your post to clarify what you mean by "a flexbox can be used to nicely adjust the size of in-flow elements". Be precise about why the flexbox behaviour is more desirable for you than regular inline flow.

I'd like to know whether there are better solutions, but here's my current solution:
That layout can be achieved by using text-align: justify instead of a flexbox.
To make the white gaps between the gray <span> elements have the same width in all rows, I use tricks to avoid expansion caused by text-align: justify.
(Before that trick, I had tried adding justify-self: stretch to the children elements, but it has no effect if the parent <div> has display: block. I in turn tried all possible display values for the parent <div>, but none of them achieve the desired result.)


.container {
  text-align: justify;
}
.container span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: gray;
}
.container .float {
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
<div class="container">justified div
  <span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span class="float">multiline<br>float</span><span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>no line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>no line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>no line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>no line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>no line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>foo</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>&#x2005;<span>span with suppressed line breaks</span>
</div>



user-select: none can prevent selection of the &#x2005; characters, but then those characters should be wrapped inside own <span>s with user-select: none (with an additional convenience of setting their width) because it seems that setting user-select: none for the parent can't be overriden by other children.
To avoid the stretched spaces, I'm thinking about adding a space character in the beginning and end of each gray <span> so that that character would do all the stretching; and wrapping the text in some tag with some CSS that would prevent the stretching or applying the same tricks to the intermediate spaces.
